# How do you turn on your Mic on Fortnite for Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher, gaming-accessories

I have only just started playing Fortnite on my Nintendo Switch which I also only just got. I know already that it is possible to talk on Fortnite - Nintendo Switch but I don't know how!! Hope someone can help!!

How do I do it (above) with a headset (with mic) connected?

Comment: the nintendo switch does not have a built in mic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the instructions in order to enable voice chat.

1. Start Fortnite and select the top menu "Settings".
2. Go to the tab "Sound", you will find below the category of "Voice Chat".
3. Select the option to `Enabled` in order to activate the Voice Chat feature.
4. Then, press `Apply` to save your changes.

I found these instructions from [here](https://technical-tips.com/blog/games/fortnite-voice-chat-enable-and-33483).

Comment: Additionally, plug-in some headphones with a mic as the Switch has no built-in mic.

Comment: I will check this when I get the chance and if it works I'll use the tick to accept the answer.

Comment: thanks it worked :-D